# CORS Access-Control-Allow-Origin not being set for 404 responses - Web Api 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, cors, asp.net-web-api2

My web api needs to have the ability to support CORS Ajax requests. I'm seeing some strange behavior where if the status code of my response message is a 404, the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is not set, but if the response message is a 200 the header IS set. The policy from MyCustomCorsPolicy attribute is being returned in all cases, but the headers don't seem to be actually set for 404s. Any ideas?

```
[HttpGet]
[MyCustomCorsPolicy]
public HttpResponseMessage myAction([FromUri] int id)
{
    var serviceResult = service.GetResultById(id);
    if (serviceResult == null)
    {
         // Responses to AJAX requests that make it here DO NOT have the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header set.
         return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "there was and issue finding the resource");
    }

    // Responses to AJAX requests that make it here have the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header set.
    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

Here is my custom CORS policy implementation:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class MyCustomCorsPolicy : Attribute, ICorsPolicyProvider
{
    private readonly CorsPolicy policy;

    public MyCustomCorsPolicy()
    {
        // Create a CORS policy.
        policy = new CorsPolicy
        {
            AllowAnyMethod = true,
            AllowAnyHeader = true,
        };

        // Set the headers to expose.
        policy.ExposedHeaders.Add("My-Custom-Header");

        // Add allowed origins.
        policy.Origins.Add("http://ajaxsourcesite.com");
    }

    public Task<CorsPolicy> GetCorsPolicyAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // This is getting hit in both cases (both 200 and 404)
        return Task.FromResult(policy);
    }
```

Comment: Maybe providing code of MyCustomCorsPolicy will be helpful